# Caching / extracting SemanticImport* settings. SemanticImportFunction?

Tags: performance-tuning, import, conversion

Using an example from [my recent answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140508/5478):

```
file = "Name    x1  x2  x3  x4  x5
    Abe -0.539010   0.75445 -1.44697    -0.06767    1.69325
    Bob -0.992619   -2.20993    1.73367 2.01081 -0.94835";

data = SemanticImportString@StringReplace[file, " " .. -> " "]
```

> [image]

we see that `SemanticImport` is really handy, though it is about 4x slower than manual approach. And it will be worse and worse as the data grows.

```
SemanticImportString @ StringReplace[file, " " .. -> " "]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.02, Null}
> ```

```
Dataset[
  Function[values, AssociationThread[# -> values]
  ] /@ {##2} & @@ ImportString[StringReplace[file, " " .. -> " "], "Table"]
]; // RepeatedTiming
```

> ```
> {0.005, Null}
> ```

It would be nice to be able to 'train' `SemanticImport` on a data sample in order to extract settings it discovered. To be able to use it on analogous examples of data, instead of writing custom converter.

Is this possible with minimal effort?